# Unable to suspend or shutdown due to WiFi card (QCA6164)

Tags: networking, suspend, shutdown

I recently started to use Linux and I've fallen in love with it, but there is something that bothers me. I cannot suspend or shutdown, it just freezes and, after some testing, I realized that I can do it with no problems if I remove my WiFi card or enter airplane mode before doing it.

Is there a way to fix this? Maybe run some commands before suspend or shutdown?

My laptop is a Lenovo g70-80 and my WiFi card is listed as QCA6164. Ubuntu 18.04.1 x86_64

Comment: Are you mounting any directories over the network (network shares)? Perhaps a samba drive?

Comment: No, but I can suspend without problem with usb wifi card and mounted directories.